# Automatic mic level control for PA

Tags: mixing, automation

I have a conference room that's big enough to require some voice amplification (15x7 m, seats ~50 people, acoustics not optimal with hard walls and a low ceiling). We currently use an ordinary analog mixing desk to control sound levels. Someone has to set up the mixer each time the room is used, and this requires some knowledge of audio (to prevent feedback), so usually a sound engineer is required to be present when the room is used. That presents scheduling issues, so I want to automate things.

My requirement is for speech amplification, 2-4 microphones, plus AV sources, with no manual setup for each use other than switching the system on. Ideally, I'd be able to set a goal for the volume in the room and have the system auto-adjust to that volume while avoiding feedback.

I haven't kept up with developments in this field. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this overkill? https://www.thomann.de/gb/sp_feedback_controllers.html Other than feedback suppression, you could just keep the mixer covered/boxed between sessions to keep idle hands off it.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a conference and meeting rooms AV system. There are many of them available.